# Example of a random variable that is integrable, but p-th moments for any p > 1 do not exist

Tags: probability, random-variables, noise, moment-problem

I have seen examples of random variables that are integrable, but the second moment does not exist. Is there an example of a random variable that is integrable, but the p-th moment, for any p > 1, does not exist?

Edit: To be precise, what I require is a random variable (ideally symmetric) such that $\mathbb{E}|X| < +\infty$ and, for any $p \in (1,2]$ (or more generally, $p > 1$, not necessarily integer), we have $\mathbb{E}|X|^p = \infty$.

Comment: Do you mean RVs for which $\mathbb{E}[X^n]$ exists only for $n=1$? Just trying to clarify.

Comment: Yes, but somewhat more stricter than the example you provided. What I require is $\mathbb{E}|X| < \infty$, but, for any $p \in (1,2]$ we have $\mathbb{E}|X|^p = \infty$. It seems to me that for Pareto, with $x_m = 1$ and $\alpha \in (1,2]$, we have $\mathbb{E}X^p < +\infty$, for any $p \in (1,\alpha)$.

Comment: Oh, I get the problem. I thought you originally meant $p$ was integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take the probability density function

$$\rho(x) = \frac{c}{(x^2+1) \log^2(x^2+2)}$$

with $c$ that makes the integral over $\mathbb{R}$ equal $1$. Let $\mu$ be the probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ given by $\rho$.  Now take on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}, \mu)$ the random variable $X(x) = x$.  Then

$$E(|X|) < \infty \\
E(|X|^p) = \infty \textrm{ for all } p> 1$$

Note: in general, the set of $p$'s such that $E(|X|^p)< \infty$ is convex  (due to Hölder's inequality; so a segment containing $0$, infinite or not ), and every such segment appears in this way.  In our example the set of $p$'s is $(-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

The [Pareto distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) with shape $\alpha =2$ (or any $1<\alpha\leq 2$) has a well-defined first moment, but all other moments diverge.
By appropriate choices of $\alpha$ you can also find distributions with $\mathbb{E}[X^p]$ being finite only up to some $p=k$.